# Crystal Report's 3 Way Formula is not working with a Two-Page Report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-xi

I am using this 3 way formula below to get record/s from details section and display in group footer for each group in a report. It is working pretty well BUT NOT WITH A GROUP REPORT CONTAINING OR EXTENDING WITH more than 1 page.

**Formula 1: In Group Header (Initialise)**

```
Whileprintingrecords;
stringvar strtitle := "";
```

**Formula 2: In details Section, (create a condition)**

```
    Whileprintingrecords;

    stringvar strtitle;
    numbervar var;

    if ({@CurrentMonthNew}) = "CLOSED" and ({@PreviousMonthNew}) <> "CLOSED"
    THEN
    strtitle := strtitle   + ChrW(13) + cstr((var := var+1;),0) + ". "  +    {spMSR;1.name} + " ceased its operation on " + cstr({@LastDate})

   else if ({@CurrentMonthNew}) <> "CLOSED" and ({@PreviousMonthNew}) = "Not    yet operational"
   THEN
   strtitle := strtitle   + ChrW(13) + cstr((var := var+1;),0) + ". "  + {spMSR;1.name} + " started its operation on " + cstr({@FirstDate})
```

**Formula 3: In Group Footer, display the final output**

```
whileprintingrecords;
stringvar strtitle;
```

Why is not working with a two or more page report and how to solve this problem? Any help will be highly appreciated.

**UPDATED:**

I have tried to uncheck the "Repeart Group Report on Each Page" and it worked, but the group header was lost. How can we have both?

Comment: Your group header is probably set to repeat on each page.

Comment: Yes it is, because I want the header format to be in every page. I tried Unchecking it, and it worked well, but how can I both have two working?

Comment: Hi @Ryan you seem so very knowledgeable in Crystal report, pls help me on this. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify formula in your group header:

```
Whileprintingrecords;
If Not InRepeatedGroupHeader Then stringvar strtitle := "";
```

Comment: This worked, a little problem arise because I have included a sequenced numbering in the notes, the numbering go back to one when in the second page part. But I'll accept this :)

Answer (score 0):

Arvo's answer is correct though a little problem arise in the sequence numbering I included in the notes.

I found out this simple work around to achieve the expected result

```
1. Place Formula 1 to Group Footer part from the Group Header.
```

after that, everything worked.